# Can't Sync UI over Unet

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, network-programming, unity-networking

I need to make playerHealth with UI. Everything works fine, but when i join with another player, i can't see the UI. I tried to make UI gameobject enabled if you are a localplayer, but that doesn't work. How to make load values of player by id like: playerHealth = playerID.health;?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class PlayerStats : NetworkBehaviour
{
 NetworkConfigurator netConf;

 [SyncVar]
 public float playerHealth;

 void Start () 
 {
     netConf = GameObject.Find ("NetworkManager").GetComponent<NetworkConfigurator> ();
     netConf.userStatus.SetActive (isLocalPlayer); // Here the problem
 }

 void Update () 
 {
     if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.LeftBracket))
     {
         if (playerHealth == 0)
             return;

         playerHealth -= 5;
     }
     if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.RightBracket))
     {
         if (playerHealth == 100)
             return;

         playerHealth += 5;
     }
     netConf.healthAmount.text = "" + playerHealth;
     netConf.healthBar.fillAmount = playerHealth / 100;
 }
}
```